# Is it possible to strip the protocol in \url?

Tags: hyperref, urls

I would like to have

```
commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Blue_Unknot.png
```

as text for the link

```
https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Blue_Unknot.png
```

As I want line-breaking, I can't use

```
\href{https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Blue_Unknot.png}{commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Blue_Unknot.png}
```

but

```
\url{https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Blue_Unknot.png}
```

shows `https://`.

Is it possible to tell get rid of the protocol in the displayed text, but still have a correct link?

## Minimal not-working example

```
\documentclass[a6paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath} % needed for math
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % this is needed for correct output of umlauts in pdf
\usepackage{hyperref}   % links

\begin{document}
    \section{url}
    Trivialer Knoten: \url{https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Blue_Unknot.png}

    \section{href}
    Trivialer Knoten: \href{https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Blue_Unknot.png}{commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Blue\_Unknot.png}

    \section{href + path}
    Trivialer Knoten: \href{https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Blue_Unknot.png}{\path{commons.wi‌​kimedia.org/wiki/File:Blue_Unknot.png}}
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: you know there should be a MWE but I'd guess `\href{https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Blue_Unknot.png}{\path{commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Blue_Unknot.png}}` using url pack's `\path` command (which I don't think hyperref touches)

Comment: This did not work (see image above). I've also added a M(n)WE.

Comment: You have two spurious characters between `wi` and `ki`

Comment: @egreg: What are "spurious characters"? Which "wiki" do you mean? How did you see that? And how can I remove them (because I can't see them!)

Comment: @moose Can't you *see* the result in the third example? Just select the word `wikipedia`, hit delete and retype it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in comments you can use `\path` (you have unrelated spurious characters in your MWE, this just deletes them)

[image]

```
\documentclass[a6paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath} % needed for math
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % this is needed for correct output of umlauts in pdf
\usepackage{hyperref}   % links

\begin{document}
    \section{url}
    Trivialer Knoten: \url{https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Blue_Unknot.png}

    \section{href}
    Trivialer Knoten: \href{https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Blue_Unknot.png}{commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Blue\_Unknot.png}

    \section{href + path}
    Trivialer Knoten: \href{https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Blue_Unknot.png}{\path{commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Blue_Unknot.png}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\section{href}
{\sloppy Trivialer Knoten: 
 \href{https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Blue_Unknot.png}%
      {commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Blue\_Unknot.png}\par}
```

may help. The text can only be hyphenated at regular hyphenation points. Or insert a space which is not misleading:

```
\section{href}
{\sloppy Trivialer Knoten: 
 \href{https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Blue_Unknot.png}%
   {commons.wikimedia.org/ wiki/File:Blue\_Unknot.png}\par}
```