# How to define a command to typeset a URL without the protocol?

Tags: macros, urls

There is a [related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156743/is-it-possible-to-strip-the-protocol-in-url), but the answer shows how manually create a link with the URL text. That's not what I want.

I want to create a command (call it `\urlb`) that will typeset a URL with a hyperlink, but discard the protocol in the link's text. It seems like something that could be done using code, but I haven't found a package that can do this.

Am I missing something?

### Example

I'd like to type:

```latex
\urlb{https://mydomain.example.com}
```

And get the hyperlinked output:

> [mydomain.example.com](https://mydomain.example.dom)

So the definition might look something like this:

```latex
\newcommand{\urlb}[1]{%
    \href{#1}{\stripProto{#1}}%
}
```

### Email addresses

I also want it to work for email addresses. In that case, the input would be `mailto:a.b@domain.com` and the output would be a hyperlink with the text `a.b@domain.com`.

Comment: see https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/125